# I want to add a custom class to the Kendo UI for Angular TabStrip

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

```
<kendo-tabstrip (tabSelect)="onTabSelect($event)">
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab title="Paris" [selected]="true">
        <ng-template kendoTabContent>
            <div class="content">
                <img src="https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/layout/assets/tabstrip/rainy.png"/>
                <h2>17<span>ºC</span></h2>
                <span>Rainy weather in Paris.</span>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
</kendo-tabstrip>
```

Here is second tab I want to add my custom class in it:

Add any condition for `[ngClass]`

```
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab title="New York City">
        <ng-template kendoTabContent>
            <div class="content">
                <img src="https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/layout/assets/tabstrip/cloudy.png"/>
                <h2>19<span>ºC</span></h2>
                <span>Cloudy weather in New York City.</span>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
```

Here is my code I want to add my custom class to second tab. I tried the `[ngclass]` and class for that but it's not working for me.

Comment: Do you mean either `kendo-tabstrip-tab` or `kendoTabContent` or `kendo-tabstrip`? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @AdrianKokot I want to show the kendo-tabstrip-tab based on condition. ex. in some conditions one tab is not visible to the user and other tabs visible.

Comment: so you want to hide/show content, not add class. Can't you just add `*ngIf` directive with appropriate condition?

Comment: @AdrianKokot I want to add and remove class to kendo-tabstrip-tab based on condition. please provide randoam example for it.

Answer (score 0):

`TabStripTabComponent` which selector is `kendo-tabstrip-tab` has `cssClass` property which accepts the same arguments as Angular `ngClass` directive.

So you can add CSS classes to `kendo-tabstrip-tab` like that:

```html
<kendo-tabstrip-tab title="Paris" [selected]="true" cssClass="my-custom-class">
  <ng-template kendoTabContent>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/layout/assets/tabstrip/rainy.png"/>
      <h2>17<span>ºC</span></h2>
      <span>Rainy weather in Paris.</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-tabstrip-tab>
```

or

```html
<kendo-tabstrip-tab title="Paris" [selected]="true" [cssClass]="{'my-custom-class-on-condition': someCondition}">
  <ng-template kendoTabContent>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/layout/assets/tabstrip/rainy.png"/>
      <h2>17<span>ºC</span></h2>
      <span>Rainy weather in Paris.</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-tabstrip-tab>
```

There's also `cssStyle` property that accepts `ngStyle` syntax. If you're interested in disabling tab, for example, you can also use `disabed` property.